# Entity framework for each loop one per one

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have method inside class which needs to remap two tables into dto, but when I loop through tables it gives me whole table instead of one record per each loop, is there a way to tell returned table to give one item per each for loop? and doing it asynchronously? currently code looks something like this:

```
var simpleDtoList = new List<DtoObject>();

using (var db = new SimpleContext())
{
     await foreach (SimpleA A in db.SimpleATable)
     {
         using (var database = new SimpleContext())
         {
             await foreach (SimpleB B in database.SimpleBTable)
             {
                   var DtoObject = new DtoObject();

                   DtoObject.Id = A.Id;
                   DtoObject.SimpleA = A.Name;
                   DtoObject.SimpleB = B.Name;

                   simpleDtoList.Add(DtoObject);
             }
        }
    }
}
return simpleDtoList;
```

I've found solution with setting Where equals index of simpleDtoList but I have to remove await, is there a way to keep await code?

Comment: I can't find a way to add async code here unless I return whole table every for each loop and append by the index of List, but request size and amount is not worth only to have async code, currently as I stated in the solution it finds one by one Where it equals List index, if anyone finds where I can put async await let me know.

Comment: Check out async+yield in c# 8 -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8

Comment: why do you make two instanes of the context?

Answer (score 0):

Whould something like the following help?

```
await foreach (SimpleB B in (from b in db.Blogs where something == "somthing").ToListAsync()))
{
     var DtoObject = new DtoObject();
     DtoObject.Id = A.Id;
     DtoObject.SimpleA = A.Name;
     DtoObject.SimpleB = B.Name;
     simpleDtoList.Add(DtoObject);
}
```